# Issue with MySql and the Greek characters using mysql for excel

Tags: mysql, excel, mysql-workbench

I used mysql for excel in order to import data from excel to mysql DB.

When I used the "Select" command in Mysql Workbench I realised that the greek Characters appeared like question marks "?"

Then I saved the excel file as .csv and opened it with notepad++ in order to encode it with utf8.

Then i used the following command and again the problem with the greek chars made even worse.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/working.csv' 
INTO TABLE tablexxx
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Can you please help me out.  Dead End here!!!

Comment: The question marks might just appear because the font you use to show the results doesn't support greek. So, try setting a different font in the Preferences of WB to a font that is know to contain greek charactes as well (e.g. Arial Unicode).

Answer (score 3):

Try the greek character set

```
CHARACTER SET CP869;
```

But usually it should work with UTF-8 maybe you need to change the settings in notepad++ or in the MySQL Workbench and the other programs you desire to use.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but where should I try the this character set?

Comment: use it instead of the line with UTF8

Comment: Sorry my friend but it is not recognized.

Comment: I think I got the answer try to add `SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'` instead of your `CHARACTER SET UTF8` and restart your DB. Check if your DB charset is UTF-8

Comment: Don't use invidiual charsets if you can use Unicode. UTF-8 is just fine for most work.